# How to inject dynamic DbContext object into repository using Autofac

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac, unit-of-work

I have an .net core web api application where I'm using entity framework core with service layer, unit of work and repository layer pattern. For DI I'm using Autofac.

The application has **multiple clients** and **each client has its own database** and the schema for all these databases is same. *With each API call I'll get the client specific connection string, using which I have to create a DbContext and use it for all its operations.*

On Startup class I have registered my dbcontext ClientDbContext and all other classes. When the unit-of-work class is  called I am creating my new DbContext based on the connection string. I want the repository to use this instance, **but the repository is still using the initial ClientDbContext instance which was created at startup**.

**How can I make the repository use the new DbContext instance?**

Unit of Work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public ClientDbContext ClientDbContext { get; private set; }        

    public UnitOfWork ()
    {            

    }

    public void SetDbContext(string connectionString)
    {
        if(ClientDbContext == null)
        {
            //creating new db context instance here
            ClientDbContext = MembershipRepository.CreateDbContext(connectionString);
        }                
    }        
    //property injection
    public IGenericRepository<SomeEntity, ClientDbContext> SomeEntityGenericRepository { get; }
}
```

Generic Repository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity, TDbContext> : IGenericRepository<TEntity, TDbContext> where TEntity : class
where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly TDbContext _context;
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _dbset;
    public GenericRepository(TDbContext context)
    {
        // need to get updated context here, but getting the initial one
        _context = context;
        _dbset = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

Autofac module called in Startup.cs:

```
builder.Register(a => new ClientDbContext()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericRepository<,>)).As(typeof(IGenericRepository<,>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

//Register Unit of Work here
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().PropertiesAutowired();                

//Register Services here
builder.RegisterType<SomeService>().As<ISomeService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Can anyone please help me out on how to achieve the above requirement?

Is there any way I can make Autofac use my new created dbcontext object?

Comment: Both the problem and the solution are probably at startup where you'r registering these dependencies. Can you show that?

Comment: @ScottHannen I have updated my question with the startup. Actually I using Autofac module which I am registering in Startup. I have given the code of the module. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks.

Comment: *With each API call I'll get the client specific connection strings* How do you get these strings? How do you recognize from the request which string you should get? You may find what you need when looking for multi-tenancy patterns.

Comment: @GertArnold In each API call I will get the client Id, using which I will call Membership repository to get the conn string and create the new db context.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
builder.Register(a => new ClientDbContext()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

you could use

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>().ClientDbContext)
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

By the way I'm not sure what is the responsibility of your `IUnitOfWork`. Another way of doing this would be to have a class that would provide information about the current user :

```
public interface IClientContext 
{
    public String ClientIdentifier { get; }
}
```

Then a `DbContextFactory` that would create the `DbContext` based on the `IClientContext`

```
public interface IDbContextFactory 
{
    IDbContext CreateDbContext(); 
}

public class DbContextFactory 
{
    public DbContextFactory(IClientContext clientContext) 
    {
        this._clientContext = clientContext; 
    }

    private readonly IClientContext _clientContext;

    public IDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        // get the connectionstring from IClientContext and return the IDbContext
    } 
}
```

The concrete implementation of `IClientContext` depends on the way you can get this information, it could be from current `HttpContext` or any other way it's up to you.
It seems that at some point you call `SetDbContext` you can keep this way by creating a `XXXClientContextProvider` where `XXX` is relative to the way you get this information.

```
public class XXXClientContextProvider 
{
    private IClientContext _clientContext; 

    public IClientContext GetClientContext()
    {
        if(this._clientContext == null) 
        {
           throw new Exception("client context is null. You should do X or Y"); 
        }
        return this._clientContext; 
    }
    public void SetClientContext(String clientId) 
    {
        if(this._clientContext != null) 
        {
            throw new Exception("client context has already been set"); 
        }
        this._clientContext = new StaticClientContext(clientId);
    }
}
```

and then register everything like this :

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IClientContextProvider>().GetClientContext())
       .As<IClientContext>()
       .InstancePerLifetime(); 

builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IDbContextFactory>().CreateDbContext())
       .As<IDbContext>()
       .InstancePerLifetime();
```

Comment: This approach will not work for my case because, at the time of Autofac registration in startup I will not have the clientId. I will receive clientId with each api call, and then I need to somehow tell autofac to override the initial dbcontext with the new dbcontext which I created using the clientId. But I'm not able to figure out how to achieve that!

Comment: My unit of work's responsibility is to provide repositories with a dbcontext and then saving the changes done on the dbcontext by the repositories.

Comment: In this case you can change the `XXXClientContextProvider` and `IClientContext` implementations. In the `SetClientContext` you can alter an existing instance.

Comment: Could you share how you retrieve the `clientId` ? Is it a parameter of every api call ? There is many way of having a good implementation of `XXXClientContextProvider`

Comment: Another solution would be not to inject the `IClientContext` which is kind of a data-like object but only the `IClientContextProvider`. I try to always avoid injecting data-like object (as opposed to service-like object) because they have different lifecycles and could be mutable

Comment: Yes, I will get clientId with every api call as a parameter in the req body. Can you tell me from where I should call `SetClientContext`? If I have to call SetClientContext from API/Service then its the same what I am doing right now. And also while autofac registration you wrote `c.Resolve<IClientContextProvider>().GetClientContext()`, how will it resolve at startup? because we dont have any specific clientId at startup.